# How do I get acces to server running on Bluemix Paas?

Tags: node.js, connection, ibm-cloud, ports, paas

Few days ago I wanted to launch my own Agario server. I assumed not to spend any money on hosting/vps etc. After a long search I found Bluemix PaaS, I put open source Agario clone Ogar (https://github.com/OgarProject/Ogar) in them and server has already started in 1523 port, but when i try to connect to this server via agario site ( connect("ws://appname.eu-gb.mybluemix.net:1523") ) I can't connect. I tried also other ways e.g. prepared agar.io link (agar.io?ip=appname.eu-gb.mybluemix.net), but nothing worked. 
Has anyone met similar problem?

Answer (score 2):

Inbound traffic is only on standard HTTP/HTTPS ports 80/443. Bluemix will tell your application what port to listen on with the VCAP_APP_PORT env variable. Inbound requests are then mapped to that port. So, once you bind to the VCAP_APP_PORT port, you should be able to connect to : ws://appname.eu-gb.mybluemix.net